# Android TV INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-tv

I am trying to test out an Android TV app on my TV. It works in the emulator and I am using Android Studio 0.8.14.

My build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kgibilterra.com.tvgame"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
}
```

I have everything installed in the SDK Manager and in AndroidManifest.xml I have

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Has anyone else figured this out with AndroidTV specifically?

Comment: `I am trying to test out an Android TV app on my TV` -- What device is it, specifically?

Comment: ADT-1, it's the dev kit they gave out at Google IO

Comment: And has your ADT-1 been updated to Lollipop already? Because you may still be running the L preview or a close-to-final Lollipop release. That'd explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK` you are facing means **device** you are trying to install your app on, is running lower version than required in your Manifest's `android:minSdkVersion`. I am almost sure your app is not requiring Lollipop to run, so you need to edit your Manifest and set these values correctly.

See docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

change the minSdkVersion value to 19. The issue will solved.